# How do I prevent taps on a subview from triggering a UITapGestureRecognizer on a parent view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitapgesturerecognizer

I added a tap recognizer to a view:

```
   UITapGestureRecognizer* tgr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
      initWithTarget:self action:@selector( onTap )];
   [view addGestureRecognizer: tgr];
```

The problem is that taps on subviews of `view` trigger `onTap`. How do I prevent that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add subview to the background of the view,  and attach tap gesture recogniser to the subview:

```
UIView* subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:view.bounds];
subview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];//or view.backgroundColor
[view addSubview:subview];
[view sendSubviewToBack:subview];
[subview addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```

Comment: Thank you! Even in Swift 4.0 this works and it is exactly a simple solution I was looking for :)

Comment: I've changed code, a small error was there (you shouldn't use a frame of the view, use bounds to get current frame for the subview).

Answer (score 6):

Suppose your `parentView` has a `subView`. You implement the following `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` method, if the touch is inside the bounds of `subView`, you return no.

```
tgr.delegate = self;

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    CGPoint locationInView = [touch locationInView:self.parentView];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.subView.frame, locationInView) ) {
        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: This really seems better to me than the approved answer. Preventing the tap instead of adding more recognizers that does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4.2 answer for an `AlertView`

Add the gesture recogniser and set the delegate:

```
let backgroundViewTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismiss))
backgroundViewTapGesture.delegate = self     
self.backgroundView.addGestureRecognizer(backgroundViewTapGesture)
self.backgroundViewTapGesture = backgroundViewTapGesture
```

Then add the extension to handle the tap

```
extension AlertView: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    // Only handle this for the background tap gesture
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
        guard gestureRecognizer == backgroundViewTapGesture, let backgroundView = gestureRecognizer.view, let alertView = self.alertContentView else {
            return true
        }

        let touchLocation = touch.location(in: backgroundView)
        return !alertView.frame.contains(touchLocation)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift:

```
public func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    let locationInView = touch.location(in: mainView)
    if debugOptionsView.isHidden {
        return true
    }
    return !debugOptionsView.frame.contains(locationInView)
}
```